# Zero-copy intra-process messages with C RCL

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this possible? I wouldn't think so since `rcl_take` requires a pointer to an already allocated message, but am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293225/zero-copy-intra-process-messages-with-c-rcl/) by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not possible at the C API level (`rcl`). Intraprocess communication (zero-copy or not) is only implemented in C++ (`rclcpp`) right now.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0